# Swift / iOS. How to jump VC keeping hierarchies

Tags: ios, swift

```
TabBar - Navi:A - aVC1 - aVC2 - aVC3
       - Navi:B - bVC1 - bVC2 - bVC3
```

When user is in bVC3 and received notification about aVC3. How to load whole hierarchy to aVC3?
I want to make to go back aVC3 → aVC2 → aVC1 by navigation bar back button.

```
bVC3 →(touch notification)→ aVC3 →(back btn)→ aVC2 →(back btn)→ aVC1
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**Code Solution:**

```
// switch to the first tab
tabBarController?.selectedIndex = 0

// reset the view controllers on the "A" stack
let aNavController = self.tabBarController?.viewControllers![0] as! UINavigationController
aNavController.popToRootViewController(animated: false)

// initialize the view controllers
let storyboard = UIStoryboard(name: "Main", bundle: nil)
let a2ViewController = storyboard.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "a2")
let a3ViewController = storyboard.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "a3")

// push them onto the navigation stack
aNavController.pushViewController(a2ViewController, animated: false)
aNavController.pushViewController(a3ViewController, animated: false)
```

This currently hard-codes the index of the tab you switch to (in this case the first, so index = 0). This also may need to be changed if you perform segues between view controllers in order to pass data or update state.

I just tried it in a new project, and it works just as you wanted.

**Structure Visualization:**

In this case, the button on the `B3` view controller switches tabs and opens the `A3` view controller, with the ability to go back to view controllers `A2` and `A1` as if they were pushed onto the navigation stack normally.

[image: screenshot of the storyboard showing navigation]